# Is it possible to make a route's model a computed / tracked property?

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane

I'm trying to have a route's model hook return some array that is constantly updated via a polling mechanism using [Ember `later`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Frunloop/later). The route file looks like this:

```
export default class IndexRoute extends Route {
  recent: [],

  init() {
    ...
    this.getRecent();
  }

  getRecent() {
    // poll data / fetch latest
    this.recent.push(newStuff);
    
    later(this, this.getRecent, 2000);
  }

  model() {
    return this.recent;
  }
}
```

Then in my controller, I wanted to create a `@computed` / `@tracked` property based on the route's `model`:

```
export default class IndexController extends Controller {
  // @tracked model; // this also didn't work
  @computed('model.@each') // this doesn't work
  get computedModel() {
    console.log('computedModel'); // prints only once, when the model hook is first run
    return this.model;
  }
}
```

I thought what [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211089/emberjs-refreshing-a-data-model-does-not-update-associated-computed-properties) suggested would have worked but it didn't :(

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286889/computed-property-in-controller-based-on-routes-model-in-emberjs) but this was for Ember 1.13 so not exactly a modern solution.

Similarly [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854340/emberjs-polling-update-routes-model-re-render-component) had outdated content too.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Alternatively I was thinking of moving the data into the Controller and making a computed property of a Controller variable instead. Taking all suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your current approach is that you are not using [Ember Array](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/MutableArray) specific functions. There is often some magic that happens when you create arrays in Ember that automatically creates them as Ember arrays (at least this was the case when using the old style syntax with `.create` and when prototype extensions were allowed). You can always explicitly create an Ember array with:

```
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default class ApplicationRoute extends Route{
  recent = A([]);
}
```

Anyway, when you just use `this.recent.push(newStuff);`, this native array prototype is not instrumented in a way that Ember's tracking/observer system can know that the a new value has been added to `this.recent` and subsequently trigger a rerender. This applies to both tracked properties as well as the traditional observer system pre-Octane.

Instead, when interacting with arrays that are being displayed in templates (ie arrays that need to be observed), you must use special `Ember.Array` specific functions `pushObject` like `this.recent.pushObject(newStuff)`.

```
getRecent() {
  // poll data / fetch latest
  this.recent.pushObject(this.current);
  this.current = this.current + 1;
    
  later(this, this.getRecent, 2000);
}
```

If you wanted to go full on tracked property style, you can avoid using the Ember array, but you must force a recompute by reassigning the array to the tracked property. Here's an example in a component

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked} from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { later } from '@ember/runloop';
export default class extends Component {
  @tracked
  trackedArray = [];

  current = 0;
    constructor(){
    super(...arguments);
    this.doPoll();
  }
    
    doPoll() {
    // essentially pushing but via a reassign with the new element
    // you could also `pushObject` here if that feels better
    this.trackedArray = [...this.trackedArray, this.current];
    this.current = this.current + 1;
    
    later(this, this.doPoll, 2000);
  }
}
```

Here is a [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8e06520705fd2cc42b379eacdc8b2c73?openFiles=components.tracked-array%5C.js%2Ctemplates.components.tracked-array%5C.hbs) that shows both approaches in action.

PS. The `model` property of a route is only quasi-dynamic. During the transition, the return value of the `model` hook is automatically assigned to the route's `currentModel` property. This value is then passed into `setupController` as the second parameter and automatically assigned to the controller's `model` property if no `setupController` is defined or if the `setupController` invokes `super` of the base implementation. When `modelFor` is called for a particular route, the `currentModel` property is returned and `model` is not reinvoked. This is all to say that having the poll in the `model` function itself would not automatically update the controller's `model` property. Everything works fine in your example since the `model` reference never changes (you're just mutating the array).

Comment: Just to add to your create explanation: The `TrackedArray` from [tracked-built-ins](https://github.com/pzuraq/tracked-built-ins) package is a great replacement for `Ember.Array`.

Comment: Ah so by "quasi-dynamic", you mean the value returned by the model hook is assigned to the `currentModel` property of the route and if it's an EmberArray, it's a reference to the EmberArray. When the internal values of the EmberArray changes, we are able to detect a change using an Ember Observer on the values of the array.

Comment: Would this still work if what's returned in the `model` hook is a JS object?
eg. `recent: {}` and then `return this.recent;` in the `model` hook