# How to pass a @tracked object from an Ember route model hook

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane

My question is two-fold:

1. Where is the best place to put some kind of polling logic - in the route file right?
2. How do I pass this constantly updating value from the Route to some child component? Labeling some variable as "`@tracked`" and then passing the tracked variable via the `model` hook?

Let's say I have something like this:

`routes/index.js`

```js
export default class IndexRoute extends Route {
  @tracked
  recent: {
    A: 0,
    ...
  },

  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.getRecent();
  }

  getRecent() {
    // poll data / fetch latest
    const {A, ...partialObject} = this.recent;
    
    this.recent = { ...partialObject, A: <some new value fetched>};;
    
    later(this, this.getRecent, 2000);
  }

  model() {
    return this.recent;
  }
}
```

`application.hbs`

```
<p>constantly updating "this.recent": {{ this.model.A }} </p>
```

I thought if I use the model hook like this, it would be tracked and therefore auto-update but that was not the case. I have this sample [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/dacd87762111202353d2fff9bd6781f4?openFiles=routes.application%5C.js%2C) that emulates what I'm trying to do. I tried to force a re-compute by reassigning the entire variable but it didn't work.

This question is a deeper dive from my [initial question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169006/is-it-possible-to-make-a-routes-model-a-computed-tracked-property).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a reference to object stored in `this.recent` in your model hook. But the `getRecent` method does not change that object but overrides `this.recent`. After the first execution of `getRecent` method the model of the route and `this.recent` aren't the same object anymore. The model of the route, which you can access through `this.modelFor(this.routeName)` is the initial value and `this.recent` is the new value.

You want to mutate the object returned from model hook instead.

The object given in your example has a fixed schema. This allows you to mark the property `A` as tracked:

```js
  recent: {
    @tracked A: 0,
    ...
  }
```

As currently you return the value of `this.recent` in your model hook. But instead of overwriting it in `getRecent` method, you are only changing the value of it's property `A`:

```js
  getRecent() {  
    this.recent.A = <some new value fetched>;
    
    later(this, this.getRecent, 2000);
  }
```

If you don't know the schema of the object returned in model hook or if you are dealing with an array, it's a little bit more complicated. You wouldn't have a property to decorate with `@tracked`. I would recommend to use the [`tracked-built-ins`](https://github.com/pzuraq/tracked-built-ins) package in that case.

For arrays you can also fallback to legacy [`MutableArray`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/MutableArray) from `@ember/array/mutable` package. But you must make sure in that case that you use it's custom methods to manipulate the array (e.g. `pushObject` instead of `push`).

Comment: Oh I figured `this.recent = { ...partialObject, A: <some new value fetched>};` would overwrite all of `this.recent` - is that not the case? :o

Comment: re: "You are returning a reference to object stored in this.recent in your model hook." - is there a way to return the actual object then? or should I not do it this way and instead add `@tracked` to each key in the object as you mentioned instead?

Comment: You are returning an object. But the returned object is not affected, when you are changing `this.recent`. Maybe this code illustrates it: Ember framework calls `this.model()`. Afterwards `this.recent === this.modelFor(this.routeName)` is true. Now `this.getRecent()` runs, which changes `this.recent`. `this.recent === this.modelFor(this.routeName)` is false. Route model hook is not autotracked. It does not rerun when a value consumed in it changes. You should not replace the object returned in it but manipulate it.

Comment: Ah so basically a copy of the object is created and passed for the value `this.modelFor(this.routeName)` and later on when `getRecent` runs, it alters the value of the original object which is not tracked because the `model` hook is not tracked (whereas something like a `get` would? i have yet to get that to work yet, maybe i shouldn't have a @tracked object in the route?)

Comment: Ah I think Ember Octane by default has a hard time tracking POJOs and I would need to write an extra layer to support it? https://guides.emberjs.com/release/in-depth-topics/autotracking-in-depth/#toc_plain-old-javascript-objects-pojos

Comment: Yeah it seems I can't set the value if I do it the way specified in the docs: I get `ember.debug.js:35800 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You attempted to update [object Object].A to "2", but it is being tracked by a tracking context, such as a template, computed property, or observer. In order to make sure the context updates properly, you must invalidate the property when updating it. You can mark the property as '@tracked', or use '@ember/object#set' to do this.`

Comment: Read some of the Ember Octane RFCs, found this gem:
`Now, with actual native POJOs, you have two options:
Invalidate the reference, or use a class with tracked properties within the class`
- so this wouldn't work with our route `model` hook example because by invalidating the reference, what the route `model` hook returned is not the same as the new native POJO.

Comment: Your issue is differently. Most of the derived state in Ember Octane is autotracked. If a tracked value consumed in a getter changes that getter is executed again. Similar to how a template helper or a modifier runs again if one of it's arguments changes. But the `model` hook is differently. It is not autotracked. That means it does not run again if a tracked value changes. It only runs in case of a transition.